# After updating rhc / httpclient I cannot execute git push

Tags: git, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I ran the rhc client update that Openshift notified me about. Now when I try pushing or cloning the git repository I get the following error:

```
git clone ssh://5432c6d9e0b8cd501e000096@storycreator-storycreator.rhcloud.com/~/git/storycreator.git/ storycreator
Cloning into 'storycreator'...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is a Windows 8 system. The other git commands work, like add and commit. Anyone else see this issue, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That errors usually means rhc can no longer see your SSH keys. Can you please open the terminal and then do

ssh -vvv 5432c6d9e0b8cd501e000096@storycreator-storycreator.rhcloud.com

Try to see where it is looking for the keys. OpenShift places them in .ssh in your home directory but I think some versions of SSH on windows look for them in the Program Files directory.